# Request HTTP libraries are slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, request

I'm making a project using Node.js (8.9.4) and Express (4.16.2). Basically, with Node.js i'm consulting an external API and then with Express make a route to consume this result. My surprise was that when I used Axios library, it make my response to delay up to ~30s. I wanted to check if it was my problem or was from the API... I've checked it with PostMan and it returns in less than 300ms. Then I've thought it was any problem related with Axios, so I've decided to use request-promise but...again 30s. The last test I've made is using Node.js native 'https' util and...yes, less than 300ms again.

Anyone knows whats the problem with those packages? Am I condemned to use callbacks instead of promises?

Here's my base code... (AXIOS, Request-Promise... 30s delay in response)

```
const rp = require('request-promise);

const BASE_URL = 'my https url';
const AUTH_TOKEN = 'my auth token';

const options = {
    uri: BASE_URL + '/my-route',
    qs: { myQS: true },
    headers: { authorization: AUTH_TOKEN }
    method: 'GET'
};

rp(options)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(error => error);
```

Here's my base code with HTTPS.... 300ms delay in response

```
const https = require('https');

const AUTH_TOKEN = 'my auth token';

const options = {
    hostname: 'my hostname',
    port: 443,
    path: 'my path',
    headers: { authorization: AUTH_TOKEN },
    method: 'GET'
};

https.get(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', d => d);
};
```

Comment: I feel there is some logic running before making `http` call...

Comment: I've encountered the same problem and wonder if you managed to find a solution? There is a very long delay in getting a response from the axios.get() version compare to https.get()

Comment: In my case, I was calling an API that makes X extra calls to another API or DB and I've solved the problem in my first API, adding some queryparams reduced my times drastically. First of all, if you have access to it, I'll check inside the API the real time of response, using for example Postman (or similar) and checking the results. Even though, place some debuggers and check if everything is as expected :).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but sounds like Axios is going via a different route in your network.  Are both requests configured to use the same proxy setup?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an API currently active in my company. I've just created a new project with Node.js 8 and Express 4 to consume it...